# Private function not returning value

Tags: javascript

I have code as below.

```
var Main = function () {
    var a, b, c, d;
    a = 1;
    b = true;
    c = undefined;

    var _private = function () {
        return 'Function with Private acceess';
    };

    this.getPublic = function () {
        return 'Function with Public access';
    };

    this.getPrivate = function () {
        _private();
    };

};

var o = new Main();
console.log(o.getPublic());
console.log(o.getPrivate());
```

In the code above I am trying to access the private method of the `Main` object `o` through the public method `getPrivate()`.
But in the console the result is

```
undefined
```

Why is the `_private` not returning the desired value?

Comment: `_private()` does its best to return a value, but `getPrivate()` does not relay it to its own caller.

Comment: Isn't this in the class of typo questions?

Comment: @Esailija, not sure. Still thinking, though.

Comment: It could be that OP has too minimal understanding or has understanding but made a typo-like mistake. :P

Comment: @Esailija, indeed, but the right angle to consider is if this question can benefit to further readers. Forgetting a `return` statement in the call chain is not a big deal in other languages (resulting in a warning at least), but not so in Javascript. There is a quick, to-the-point, upvoted answer. Keeping this question open looks like the better choice here.

Comment: In Java this would be a compile time error, in C, C++ a compile-time warning, in Perl the value of the last expression would be returned...

Comment: Thanks Esailija and Hamidi for the useful comment.

Comment: Just one more clarification here, in the scope of getPrivate, the _private is a closure(this is what I can clearly see from the scope variables of chrome dev tools), so I can't call a closure like this and instead I need to return it so that it can execute it's statements. Does this makes any sense?

Comment: You should maybe look into how constructor functions are usually applied. Currently it looks like you're not using prototype at all and may as well use a function returning an object literal (if you want to use private value properties) or properly implement constructor functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the `return` statement. Try the following:

```
this.getPrivate = function () {
    return _private();
};
```

If no value is explicitly returned from a Javascript function, the function is considered to return `undefined`; no warning will be emitted.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to "return" the value.

```
this.getPrivate = function () {
    return _private();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Oops..you forgot to return value...try this

```
var Main = function () {
    var a, b, c, d;
    a = 1;
    b = true;
    c = undefined;

    var _private = function () {
        return 'Function with Private acceess';
    };

    this.getPublic = function () {
        return 'Function with Public access';
    };

    this.getPrivate = function () {
        return _private();
    };

};

var o = new Main();
console.log(o.getPublic());
console.log(o.getPrivate());
```

Answer (score 0):

change like this `return  _private()`;